# R: Transforming a vector into a list of arguments

Tags: r

I would like to apply a function to a vector. However, the function is expecting a sequence of arguments. Thus, I need to "split" the vector into unrelated arguments.

Suppose that I have a dataframe called *dta*. I want to run a function, say *mean* on one of its column, say DV.

The following shows the problem

```
call("mean", dta$DV)
```

returns

```
mean(c(0.371, -0.860, etc... ))
```

The fact that the column is a vector is not compatible with the function *mean* which expects a sequence of arguments, not combined.

The solution should work if "mean" is replaced by a variable containing a string, e.g.

```
fun <- "mean"

call( fun, dta$DV)
```

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming you mean "a function", not `mean` specifically, since it literally requires a single vector, not a sequence of arguments. With `mean`, I would use `do.call("mean", list(dta$DV))`. But if you have a function that is opposite (requires singleton arguments), you might use `do.call("otherfunc", as.list(dta$DV))`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok, so I may not have understood the problem. Still, why the above call does not return a number?

Comment: If you read [`?call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/call), it says that *"'call' returns an unevaluated function call"*, where "unevaluated" is the key takeaway. You could do `eval(call(...))` (with does return the average), but then again you can also just do `do.call(...)` as in my previous comment.

Comment: @r2evans: if you put your comment into an answer, I'll validate it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R has functions that are not completely consistent. For instance, `min` and `max` accept arbitrary numbers of arguments, where all unrecognized arguments are considered in the mathematical calculation. `mean` is not, it must have all numbers to be considered as the first (or named `x=`) argument.

```r
min(1,20,0)
# [1] 0
min(c(1,20,0))
# [1] 0
mean(1,20,0) # might not be what one would expect
# [1] 1
mean(c(1,20,0))
# [1] 7
```

For the curious, the 20 and 0 are not ignored, the first `mean` call is interpreted as `mean(0, trim=20, na.rm=0)` (where `na.rm=0` is effectively the same as `na.rm=FALSE`).

Your use of `call` is a little off. From the help [`?call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/call),

> *call returns an unevaluated function call*

which doesn't really help you a lot. You might do `eval(call(...))`, but that seems silly in light of this next function.

Use of `do.call` is a bit more straight forward. I can take as its first argument: a function (anonymous or named) or a character string which matches a function. There are actually speed differences between using one or the other, so I tend to use a `character` reference to the function name when able. (I don't recall the reference that quantifies this assertion, I'll include it if I find it soon.)

For functions like `min` above that can accept any number of arguments, one can do this:

```r
args <- c(1,20,0)

as.list(args)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 20
# [[3]]
# [1] 0
do.call("min", as.list(args)) # == min(1,20,0)
# [1] 0

list(args)
# [[1]]
# [1]  1 20  0
do.call("min", list(args)) # == min(c(1,20,0))
# [1] 0
```

However, for `mean` and similar, you need to force the latter behavior:

```r
do.call("mean", list(args)) # == mean(c(1,20,0))
# [1] 7
```

For you to call a function with programmatically-defined arguments, you need to use `do.call`.